# Trying to implement cascade deletes on link table with 2 FK relationships to parent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 tables which represents

parent -< child "library item" records all in one "library item" table. To do this I have used a link table so

```
LibraryItem- Parent -< LibraryItemLink(StdLibraryItemId_Parent)
           - Child  -< LibraryItemLink(StdLibraryItemId_Child)
```

I would like to put cascade deletes on the FKs so that if one delete a Parent record from LibraryItem, all associated LibraryItemLink records are deleted, and also if any child libraryItem record is deleted the same applies.

The T-SQL for added the constraints is:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.StdLibraryItemLink
ADD
  CONSTRAINT FK_StdLibraryItemLink_StdLibraryItem_Child FOREIGN KEY (StdLibraryItemId_Child) REFERENCES dbo.StdLibraryItem (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT FK_StdLibraryItemLink_StdLibraryItem_Parent FOREIGN KEY (StdLibraryItemId_Parent) REFERENCES dbo.StdLibraryItem (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

The error I get back is:

```
Msg 1785, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_StdLibraryItemLink_StdLibraryItem_Parent' on table 
'StdLibraryItemLink' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or 
ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

This I guess is the critical bit:

```
may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths
```

Advice on how to implement a Cascade Delete on both relationship would be appreciated as logically it seems correct, ie a Parent delete and a Child delete, both requiring independent deletes of associated link records.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FK constraint declaration should be

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.StdLibraryItemLink
ADD
  CONSTRAINT FK_StdLibraryItemLink_StdLibraryItem_Child FOREIGN KEY 
  (StdLibraryItemId_Child) REFERENCES dbo.StdLibraryItem (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

**EDIT:**

Yes, it's not allowed in `SQL Server`. Moreover think for a moment, you will find that it makes no sense; cause even if you have only one referencing column then also the delete will be cascaded and the child/derived table rows will get deleted. What's the point in having multiple column referencing same table same column (IT'S OF NO BENEFIT)?

Moreover, would had it been allowed; you would have got an undesired result. To prove that, I tried the same scenario in `MySQL` where it's allowed (For your reference, below queries can be used, in case you want to try).

Parent Table

```
create table t(id int not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(10));
insert into t(`name`) values('heeli'),('holi'),('heelda');
```

Child Table

```
create table t1(id1 int,id2 int, col varchar(10),
constraint fk1 foreign key (id1) references t(id) on delete cascade,
constraint fk2 foreign key (id2) references t(id) on delete cascade); 

insert into t1 values(1,1,'holi'),(2,2,'holi'),(2,3,'holi');

select * from t1

 id1, id2, col
'1', '1', 'holi'
'2', '2', 'holi'
'2', '3', 'holi'
```

Delete a row from t now

```
delete from t where id = 2
```

Since in `t1` id1 and id2 both pointing to `t` id column; both 2nd and 3rd row will be deleted which is a undesired result in many cases.

```
select * from t1
```

Resultant data in `t1` after delete in parent table

```
 id1, id2, col
'1', '1', 'holi'
```

Comment: Thanks for this. There are only 2 tables, LibraryItem and LibraryItemLink. The FK, "StdLibraryItemId_Child", references Id on LibraryItem, as does "StdLibraryItemId_Parent", but I get the cyclic error. I am also puzzled why adding an extra ID column which references back to LibraryItem's ID will make any difference since this is what the other FKs do anyway. Also I have a PK on LibraryItemLink called ID. I may be misunderstanding your comprehensive answer, but I would appreciate further comment based on the information in this comment. Thanks

Comment: @SamJolly, in that case in your `LibraryItemLink` table have only one column referencing the `LibraryItem` table. See edited answer.

Comment: Thanks again. Still a little confused as there are 2-3 FKs in your answer. Would you be so kind to remove what does not apply. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this. Will this only implement one foreign key? I was hoping to use 2 foreign relationship, one pointing to a parent record, and the other to a child record. Whether one deletes the parent or child in the master table, a cascade delete should fire to remove the linked records in the link table. However I cannot setup a cascade on both Fks due to cyclic error. This is the core of my question. Currently I am making do with one cascade delete on my child FK since this is the most common delete situation. Is it possible to have 2 FKs with Cascade deletes?

Comment: @SamJolly, yes sure you can have but both FK must point to different table (different columns) and not the same table. In your case you trying to point to same table (id column) and so ending up cyclic error.

Comment: @SamJolly, Your post is bit ambiguous. Edit your Post and include  table schema as well as how you are trying to make relationship b/w the tables. may be then I can help further.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. Really appreciate your help. Out of interest I thought you could have 2 FKs back to the same table but pointing to different records ie parent and child. I think this is fine, but are you saying if you do this, then you will have to accept one FK not having a cascade delete. Thanks

Comment: @SamJolly, yes got it right. See edited answer (the part after `EDIT`). Further, I would suggest read about `REFERENCIAL INTEGEITY` and `FORIEGN KEY` constraint in MSDN.